# PHP-Mysql : Php echo values from sql out put from 1st and second row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to build a web page (using css) that shows me values for today and tomorrow. I can successfully get the values for today but cannot see / get the values for tomorrow which are on the next row. I require the next row column `Fajr Begins` on my webpage (php code).

Mysql query:

```
select *  from prayers where Date IN (CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) LIMIT 2;
```

output:

```
| Date       | Day  | Fajr Begins | Fajr Jamaat | Sunrise | Zohr Begins | Zohr Jamaat | Asr Begins | Asr Jamaat | Magrib Begins | Magrib Jamaat | Isha Begins | Isha Jamaat | Jumah 1 | Jumah 2 | Day of week |
+------------+------+-------------+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+---------+---------+-------------+
| 2021-10-15 | Fri  | 05:33       | 06:00       | 07:23   | 12:50       | *           | 15:33      | 16:15      | 18:11         | 18:16         | 19:59                 |   | 13:20   | 14:15   |
| 2021-10-16 | Sat  | 05:34       | 06:15       | 07:24   | 12:50       | 13:30       | 15:32      | 16:00      | 18:09         | 18:14         | 19:57                 |   | 13:20   | 14:15   |
+------------+------+-------------+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+------------+
```

All the column names are the same so I cannot alias them (which wouldve been easy)..

Here is my PHP Script (I've only taken a small snippet from the first entry of the html table):

```
 <?php
 include "dbConn.php"; // Using database connection file here
 $records = mysqli_query($db,"select *  from prayers where Date IN (CURDATE(), 
  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) LIMIT 2;" ); // fetch data from database

  while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
 {
 ?>

    <div class="u-table u-table-responsive u-table-1">
      <table class="u-table-entity">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="100%">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody class="u-table-body">
          <tr style="height: 118px;">
            <td class="u-align-center u-table-cell u-table-cell-1"><?php echo $data['Fajr 
   Begins']; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="u-table u-table-responsive u-table-2">
      <table class="u-table-entity">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="100%">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody class="u-table-body">
          <tr style="height: 118px;">
            <td class="u-align-center u-table-cell u-text-palette-3-base u-table-cell-2"><?php 
   echo $data['Fajr Jamaat']; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="u-table u-table-responsive u-table-3">
      <table class="u-table-entity">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="100%">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody class="u-table-body">
          <tr style="height: 72px;">
            **<td class="u-align-center u-table-cell u-text-palette-2-base u-table-cell-3">Tommorrow Data</td>**
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  <?php 
  }
  ?>

   <?php mysqli_close($db); // Close connection ?>
```

Webpage attached.

I've exhausted all my options searching but cannot find what the solution.
Please help pro's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is returning the correct data and is limited to two rows. When you come to create the HTML tables your `while` loop is only reading one row at a time, so you never see tomorrow's data.

However, there's no guarantee which order the data is returned in, so you need to add an `ORDER BY Date ASC` clause.

Since you're only returning two rows you don't need a `while` statement. You just need two successive fetches, something like this:

```
<?php
 include "dbConn.php"; // Using database connection file here

// Query updated to include an ORDER BY clause

 $records = mysqli_query($db,"select *  from prayers where Date IN (CURDATE(), 
  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) ORDER BY Date ASC LIMIT 2;" ); // fetch data from database

// read first row with today's data
$todaysData = mysqli_fetch_array($records);

// Create table for today here

// Now read second row, with tomorrow's data.
$tomorrowData = mysqli_fetch_array($records);

// Create table for tomorrow here.

mysqli_close($db);  // not strictly required since PHP will do this anyway
```